# How can I use the gRPC template in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm trying to create a server-client communication using gRPC.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and try to create a new project with gRPC template however it does not appear as an option.

How can I add the gRPC template to Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [Prerequisites-section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start#prerequisites) of the tutorial in the microsoft docs, you'll need Visual Studio 2019. VS 2017 is not going to work because .NET Core 3 is not supported and the gRPC-Service requires .NET Core 3 or later.

> [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=inline+link&utm_content=download+vs2019) with the **ASP.NET and web development** workload
>
> [.NET Core 3.0 SDK or later](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)